# Loop to print name, removing one character at a time

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm having a little trouble creating a program which prints out the name of the user downwards that always removes the first character each row then when it's at the last letter go up again.

This is what i have so far:

```
name = input("Put in a name: ")
name_length = len(name)

for counter in range(name_length,0, -1):    
    print(counter)
```

Below Is what it is supposed to end like

[image]

Comment: nafn isn't defined anywhere

Comment: Don't print the counter itself -- print slices of the string where the size of the slice is determined by the counter.

Comment: Try this: `s='Bilbo'` then try: `for i,c in enumerate(s): print c+s[i+1:]` Once you see that, the rest is easy....

Comment: @Andrew, sorry that was a mistake I did. I translated everything to english so you could understand

Comment: @dawg, I haven't learned "enumerate" yet and I'm in school and i'm supposed to use for in range something

Comment: @JohnColeman, How would I do that?

Comment: I imagine that, being in school, you were also supposed to solve the problem yourself, but here we are.

Comment: Hahah, my teacher actually told me if I were stuck on something to check on this website and ask for help

Answer (score 1):

I think it will work:

```
name = input("Put in a name: ")
for i in range(len(name)):          # for 1st half
    print(name[i:])
for i in range(len(name)-2,-1,-1):  # for 2nd half
    print(name[i:])
```

**Input:**

```
stack
```

**Output:**

```
stack
tack
ack
ck
k
ck
ack
tack
stack
```

I Split output into two halfs:

1st half:

```
stack
tack
ack
ck
k
```

Which will be achieved by 1st `for` loop using Slice (check to understand more [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation))

And 2nd half:

```
ck
ack
tack
stack
```

**Note:** You can print single character in this example `k` in 1st `for` loop like i do  or in 2nd `for` loop, it up to you.

Hope this helps.

Although I think you should use solution suggested by @Andrew it's pretty cool if you `print a` in his solution you get the sequence `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]` for slice the string so can be done in single `for` loop

Comment: Oh Thanks, I really appreciate your help. This website has amazing responses.

Answer (score 0):

This is an approach that just uses a single loop and slicing to achieve the same end. It creates a list of the indices at which the slice should begin, and then steps through that list printing as it goes.

```
name = "Bilbo"

a = range(len(name))
a = a[:-1] + a[::-1]

for idx in a:
    print name[idx:]
```

Comment: I think you mean `print name[idx:]` instead of `print name[a:]`

Answer (score 0):

Recursive answer

Essentially, print the same string twice, but in-between call the function again, but with the first character removed. When the start index is greater than the length of the string - 1, then you have one character left.

```
def printer(str, start=0):
    s = str[start:]
    if len(str) - 1 <= start:
        print s
        return
    print s
    printer(str, start + 1)
    print s
```

Output

```
Put in a name: cricket_007
cricket_007
ricket_007
icket_007
cket_007
ket_007
et_007
t_007
_007
007
07
7
07
007
_007
t_007
et_007
ket_007
cket_007
icket_007
ricket_007
cricket_007
```